# Page assets (html, css, js) loading animation with percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How do we achieve page assets (html, css, js and images) loading animation with percentage indicator through ajax or some other plugins?

Example: Most of the websites from http://awwwards.com

Sample one: http://www.lafamiliaxsiempre.cl/

I tried with the following code and stuck with when multiple files to download.
Please check the below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: "Titillium Web";
      font-size: 15px;
    }

    #demo-container {
      width: 400px;
      margin: 60px auto;
    }

    #download-button {
      background-color: white;
      color: #2980b9;
      border: 2px solid #2980b9;
      font-family: inherit;
      outline: none;
      min-width: 100px;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: inherit;
      border-radius: 2px;
      cursor: pointer;
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #start-download {
      text-align: center;
      display: none;
    }

    #download-progress-container {
      border: 1px solid #cccccc;
      padding: 4px;
      display: none;
      height: 20px;
    }

    #download-progress {
      background-color: #2980b9;
      display: inline-block;
      height: 100%;
    }

    #save-file {
      color: #2980b9;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: none;
      text-align: center;
    }

    #save-file:hover {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="demo-container">
    <button id="download-button">Download</button>
    <div id="download-ui-container">
      <div id="start-download">Starting Download..</div>
      <div id="download-progress-container">
        <div id="download-progress"></div>
      </div>
      <a id="save-file">Save File</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    var _OBJECT_URL;

    document.querySelector('#download-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(e) {
        if (request.readyState == 2 && request.status == 200) {
          document.querySelector('#start-download').style.display = 'block';
          document.querySelector('#download-button').style.display = 'none';
        } else if (request.readyState == 3) {
          document.querySelector('#download-progress-container').style.display = 'block';
          document.querySelector('#start-download').style.display = 'none';
        } else if (request.readyState == 4) {
          _OBJECT_URL = URL.createObjectURL(request.response);

          document.querySelector('#save-file').setAttribute('href', _OBJECT_URL);
          document.querySelector('#save-file').setAttribute('download', "file-name.avi"); //here i wish to download all the html, css, js, and image files 

          document.querySelector('#save-file').style.display = 'block';
          document.querySelector('#download-progress-container').style.display = 'none';

          setTimeout(function() {
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(_OBJECT_URL);
            document.querySelector('#download-button').style.display = 'block';
            document.querySelector('#save-file').style.display = 'none';
          }, 60 * 1000);
        }
      });
      request.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
        var percent_complete = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
        document.querySelector('#download-progress').style.width = percent_complete + '%';
      });
      request.responseType = 'blob';
      request.open('get', 'file-name.avi'); //here i wish to download all the html, css, js, and image files 
      request.send();
    });
  </script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Just a tip, DO NOT let your users sit and wait, staring at a percentage downloader. They won't visit many times if something like that will show all the time. Page load performance is the BEST feature ever.

Comment: Yes... that's right... but sometimes there are some exceptions may arise, at that time I would like to entertain the user to some extent...